# Upload multipart/form-data to alfresco with php 5.4.3

Tags: php, curl, alfresco

Hi I have a problem when I can try to upload a file with properties and metadata to alfresco 5.2 using php 5.4.3, this is my code:

```
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($lo_document['tmp_name']),
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/-root-/children",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pam['body'],
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: ".$la_auth['Authorization'],
            "accept: application/json",
             "content-type: multipart/form-data"
        )
));
```

$pam['body'] is like this:

```
-----------------------60061ddb32c3445516be40d631852702
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

patatas.pdf
-----------------------60061ddb32c3445516be40d631852702
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nodeType"

mutua:documentoMutualista
-----------------------60061ddb32c3445516be40d631852702
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="CS-08940-00227056-1.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

-----------------------60061ddb32c3445516be40d631852702--
```

This show this error:

```
{"error":{"errorKey":"No disk space available","statusCode":409,"briefSummary":"05140331 No disk space available","stackTrace":"For security reasons the stack trace is no longer displayed, but the property is kept for previous versions","descriptionURL":"https://api-explorer.alfresco.com"}}
```

But this error means one parameter or more are wrong but I don't know which,Server has a lot of disk space.

Any help? anybody works with ApiRest Alfresco 5.2 and PHP?

Comment: Are you sure you have space where your "alf_data" folder is, on your database server and so on? Have a look at this issue, are you sure you post your body ok?

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/REPO-24

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I can upload files with POSTMAN and with CURL in cmd console, but I can't do it the same with PHP, so I discard this possibility

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue uploading a file with JavaScript in a browser environment where status `409` with an errorKey `No disk space available` was returned from the alfresco backend, but the same `POST` request in Postman or CURL worked without problems.

The solution was to **not** add the HTTP header `"content-type: multipart/form-data"`, because it already contained an `multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334` header, if no custom content-type header was added.

*Refrences:*

- [Why it workeds in
  Postman: Postman adds content-type with boundry automatically](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576)
- [multipart/form-data Syntax with boundary
  Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Syntax)